# Simple C Program Lags [Homework]

Tags: c, gdb

For an assignment I have we are to find vulnerabilities in a certain C program and exploit them using various buffer overflow attacks. However when I run the .out file in the terminal with it's input argument it just stalls and doesn't do anything.

Even when I run GDB, that just lags too. I'm not looking for a solution to the assignment, I'm just looking for reasons why it's not running?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void partialwin()
{
  printf("Achieved 1/2!\n");
}

void fullwin(){
  printf("Achieved 2/2\n");
}
void vuln(){
  char buffer[36];
  
  gets(buffer);
  printf("Buffer contents are %s\n",buffer);
}

int main(int argc,char**argv){
  vuln();
}
```

Comment: What do you think is supposed to happen??? You have to enter a string on the console and then hit enter to unblock the call to `gets`.

Comment: `gets` - what's your input?

Comment: Do you pipe smth into STDIN?  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm

Comment: I did enter a string but it justs lags and doesn't print the buffer.

Comment: Google _c gets_ and you should be able to find out yourself

Comment: Please show what exactly you type and the output you get. Your code works fine here. Did you press Enter after entering the string? Just type `Hello`[Enter] and the program should display `Buffer contents are Hello`

Comment: `./assignment1.o hello` This is what I entered in my terminal. However nothing happens apeart from the cursor on the terminal blinking after I hit enter

Comment: How do you compile? Also try this: `./assignment1.o`[Enter]`Hello`[Enter]

Comment: Ah problem solved my bad, thank you @Jabberwocky it worked by hitting enter twice. Sorry my brain isn't turned on today

Answer (score 0):

Providing your sourc file is called `assignment1.c` and you're using `gcc` this should work, `$`  being your command prompt (which could be different on your platform)

```
$ gcc assignment1.c
$ a.out
Hello
Buffer contents are Hello
$
```